# System libraries in Linux vs. Windows

Tags: linux, windows, shared-libraries

My background is in Windows and I'm a Linux noob. Still trying to wrap my head around some basic concepts, and specifically the system libraries:

1. Windows has ntdll.dll which wraps system calls, and a CRT dll
   which interface between the C syntax to the ntdll OS-exposed
   services.
   (for simplification I ignore the intermediate layer of
   user32, kernel32, kernalbase etc.  I also realize the CRT is several dlls, this is not the point).
2. It seems Unix/Linux has pretty much just libc, which wraps system calls *and* called directly from your application code.

Is this the right analogy?  (ntdll + CRT)    <===> libc ?

I realize that C & Unix evolved together, but am still surprised. Can it be that the C interface is hard-wired into the OS for Unix/Linux?  In Windows non-C programs link against the underlying OS provided dlls. Is it possible that in Linux there is no OS/C-runtime border?

Comment: libc *is* the border, yes. It translates functions like `open()` or whatever into the appropriate kernel syscall.

Comment: POSIX system functions in the Windows C runtime are more often than not a poor fit and too limiting. Most native programs use the Windows API directly, e.g. `CreateFileW` -> `NtCreateFile`. Or they use the C++ standard template library plus the Windows API. Calling WINAPI DLLs an "intermediate layer" is significantly misrepresenting typical usage.

Comment: Also, the system service table in the kernel gets extended by the Windows subsystem kernel driver, win32k.sys, and these system calls are wrapped by win32u.dll in user mode, not by the base system DLL, ntdll.dll. Prior to Windows 10, these win32k system calls were made directly in user32.dll and gdi32.dll.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, most programs link against libc, even if they are written in another language.  It provides the C standard library interface (like MSVCRT), POSIX features (the equivalent of certain parts of the Win32 subsystem), and wrappers around system calls.  For example, Rust uses libc because it provides a portable environment to link against.

However, on Linux, you don't *have to* link against libc.  Go chooses to make system calls directly, which means it can ship static binaries that have no runtime dependencies.  This is possible because Linux guarantees a stable kernel ABI, but not all operating systems do this (e.g., macOS).  So unless you have significant resources (like an entire programming language team), this isn't generally a smart move unless you're only working with a handful of syscalls.

I should point out that even Windows is intrinsically wired into the C language: it uses C strings (granted, usually wide C strings) for its system calls, and much of the kernel is written in C.  Even if you were starting a kernel from scratch, you'd still need a general C interface, because virtually every programming language has a way to interact with C.

Comment: The Windows API uses C null-terminated strings, but the NTAPI (e.g. the kernel and native NT applications such as smss.exe, csrss.exe, etc) generally uses counted strings, such as [`UNICODE_STRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ntdef/ns-ntdef-_unicode_string). NT is primarily written in C and assembly. But, unlike Linux, NT does not have a stable system call interface (system calls need to use stub functions in ntdll.dll and win32u.dll) or even a stable API except for the subset that's published for driver developers.

Answer (score 3):

The Linux [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) are documented in [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) and are the foundation of user-land programs. The [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) are documented in the [ABI](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf) specifications. The [ELF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) executable format is documented, e.g. in [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html).

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) and about the [Unix philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy).

You can make system calls directly in assembler. The [Linux Assembly HowTo](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) explains that. You'll prefer to use the C interface, and for that reason the `libc` is preferable. In practice, the  `libc.so` is the cornerstone of most Linux systems.

Play with [ldd(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html), [pmap(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pmap.1.html), [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html), [BusyBox](https://www.busybox.net/)

The [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler enables useful [language extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), and [mixing C and assembler](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Using-Assembly-Language-with-C.html) code.

Some programming languages implementations are barely using C and could call system calls directly (look into [SBCL](https://sbcl.org/) or [Go](https://golang.org/) ...)

Both the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/) and usual [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) (or [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/)), and also the [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler and the [binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html) or [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_source), and you can **study their source code**.

Things become trickier with [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) and [vdso(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html).

See also http://linuxfromscratch.org/

Graphical applications are using some [display server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server), often [Xorg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_server) or [Wayland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayland_(display_server_protocol)). Read about [X11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). You would want to use GUI toolkits like [GTK](https://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](https://qt.io/) to code them.

Comment: Thanks for all the resources.